# Scala 2.10 seems to lose precision in BigDecimal

Tags: java, scala, bigdecimal

The following test passes in Scala 2.11 and 2.12 but fails as shown for 2.10

```
class JsonToXmlParserTest extends Suite with Matchers with AssertionsForJUnit {
  @Test
  def testBigDecimalPrecision(): Unit = {
    val decimalString = "12345678901234567890.12345678901234567890"
    val bigDecimal = BigDecimal(decimalString)
    val javaBigDecimal = new java.math.BigDecimal(decimalString)

    javaBigDecimal.compareTo(bigDecimal.bigDecimal) should be(0)
  }

}
```

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: -1 was not equal to 0
    at org.scalatest.MatchersHelper$.indicateFailure(MatchersHelper.scala:346)
    at org.scalatest.Matchers$ShouldMethodHelper$.shouldMatcher(Matchers.scala:6668)
    at org.scalatest.Matchers$AnyShouldWrapper.should(Matchers.scala:6704)
```

See the debugger output below, the breakpoint was on the test assertion

[image: Debugger Screenshot]

Is `BigDecimal` precision a known issue in Scala 2.10?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `toString` for anything, you should only *look* at it during debugging, and not use it for anything else. Is there any actual problem with the calculations, or is it just a sloppy `toString` implementation? Have you tried specifying the format explicitly rather than letting `toString` do some best-effort attempt to display the number? [This here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9670) seems vaguely related.

Comment: @andreytyukin I just simplified it to use `toString()` to demonstrate the issue but it's not just with `toString()`

Comment: Can you unsimplify it then? `toString` seems to be pretty essential to your test

Comment: I updated the question to remove reliance on `toString()` and instead compare the value for `java.math.BigDecimal` to `scala.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: Could it be that Scala uses some kind of default precision or scale, e.g. a scale of 14? I don't know Scala, but that was the problem in a similar question for a different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the default `MathContext` in use.  Scala 2.10 is using a `MathContext` with a precision of 34 characters, Scala 2.11 seems to be using one with a precision of 40 characters.  To solve this I can specify the `MathContext` to use unlimited precision so changing the test as follows passes for all scala versions

```
class JsonToXmlParserTest extends Suite with Matchers with AssertionsForJUnit {
  @Test
  def testBigDecimalPrecision(): Unit = {
    val decimalString = "12345678901234567890.12345678901234567890"
    val bigDecimal = BigDecimal(decimalString, MathContext.UNLIMITED)
    val javaBigDecimal = new java.math.BigDecimal(decimalString, MathContext.UNLIMITED)

    javaBigDecimal.compareTo(bigDecimal.bigDecimal) should be(0)
  }

}
```

Comment: Aha! As I expected (see my comment on question).